# How to get Planck length in meters to 6 decimal places

Tags: output-formatting, physics, units

I want Mathematica to format quantities to more decimal places than the default.

For example I have tried

```
NumberForm[
  N[
    UnitConvert[Quantity["PlanckLength"] , "Meters" ] 
    ,6] 
 ,{6, 6}]
```

[image]

This is unfortunately incorrect.

I also tried:

```
QuantityForm[UnitConvert[Quantity["PlanckLength"], "Meters" ], LongForm"]
```

but this produces an ugly representation:

[image]

I want it to produce an output like the first result (except correct to 6 decimal places).

From Wikipedia and other resources on the web it seems that this quantity is known to 6 decimal places (by default Mathematica truncates it to 4 decimal places.)

[image]

Comment: The Planck length depends on the gravitational constant, which isn't known to ten digits. So even if you forced Mathematica somehow to give you ten digits, they would be meaningless because physically unknown (smaller than the current error bar on the Planck length).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it arises from a misconception of physical measurement uncertainty.

Comment: It seems to be known to 6 decimal places on wikipedia. I will change my question from 10 to 6. (Mathematica only formats it to 4 decimal places)

Comment: This is an instance of a more general question regarding Mathematica's default output form for quantities with units. I chose 10 to accentuate my point. Not because I was interested in knowing the Planck length to 10 decimal places. I hope it is a valid question with 6 decimal places.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `4.652...` at the end of `` 1.61625500000000006684132`4.652207380644164*^-35 `` should tell you that *Mathematica* knows this constant only up to `4.65` decimal digits.

You have to enforce first to treat the number as a higher precision number first:

```
NumberForm[
 SetPrecision[
  QuantityForm[UnitConvert[Quantity["PlanckLength"], "Meters"], 
   "LongForm"], 7],
 {7, 6}]
```

> 1.616255 * 10^-35 meters

Comment: what does "up to 4.65 digits" mean?

Comment: Well, as you might know, floating point numbers are actually stored as binary numbers. "up to 4.65 digits" means that the mantissa stores a certain number of binary digits that leads converts to something close to 4.65 digits. If I am not mistaken, this corresponds to something like 15 to 16 binary digits. But actually, _Mathematica's_ finite precision numbers consist of a number (e.g. 1.61625500000000006684132) and a diameter of an interval (e.g. `10^-4.652207380644164` times the number) in which the actuall value is believed to lie in.

Comment: So the "4.65 digits" describe something like a "confidence interval"

Answer (score 14):

You can use the relative uncertainty `1.1*10^-5` from the [CODATA website](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?plkl) you also referenced, and use `Around` to construct a value for the Planck length with uncertainty which has a much nicer formatting for showing the relevant digits of the number:

```
Around[UnitConvert[Quantity["PlanckLength"], "m"], Scaled[1.1*^-5]]
```

> (1.616255±0.000018) x 10^-35 m

Since the relative uncertainty is also encoded in the precision of the number in Mathematica like Henrik pointed out, we can also use that to compute the relative uncertainty (the precision of the number representation in Mathematica not always coincides with the measurement uncertainty, but in this specific case it does):

```
Around[#, Scaled[10^-Precision[#]]] &[UnitConvert[Quantity["PlanckLength"], "m"]]
```

> (1.61626±0.00004) x 10^-35 m

which is for some reason off by a factor of two. Correcting that factor gives the same result as earlier:

```
Around[#, Scaled[0.5*10^-Precision[#]]] &[UnitConvert[Quantity["PlanckLength"], "m"]]
```

> (1.616255±0.000018) x 10^-35 m

Comment: Ah, very neat to use `Around`. Have to rembember that (+1).